# Apply specific Styles to lines in a MultiGeometry in KML

Tags: kml

Hello I have a multigeometry How has a Style like a rollover when you pass the mouse appair the lines, My question is the diferents linestring in the multigeometry have differents colors that possible?.

In the next example I have the placemark Durham Tees Valley when you select have a style but  I would like have the two lines with differents colors.

Thanks

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.2">
<Document>
<name>UK &amp; Ireland, Flight Maps</name>
<open>1</open>
        <LookAt>
            <longitude>-3.478829007934099</longitude>
            <latitude>52.50255557278696</latitude>
            <altitude>0</altitude>
            <range>730703.2034581316</range>
            <tilt>53.03089122623036</tilt>
            <heading>30.72599120906411</heading>
        </LookAt>


  <Style id="test">
    <LineStyle>
      <color>ff235523</color>
      <width>0.5</width>
    </LineStyle>
  </Style>

<Style id="doc"><ListStyle><ItemIcon><state>open closed</state><href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/airports.png</href></ItemIcon></ListStyle></Style>
<Style id="airportfolder"><ListStyle><ItemIcon><state>open closed</state><href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_circle_highlight.png</href></ItemIcon></ListStyle></Style>
<Style id="info"><ListStyle><listItemType>checkHideChildren</listItemType><ItemIcon><state>open closed</state><href>http://www.barnabu.co.uk/files/icons/info.png</href></ItemIcon></ListStyle></Style>
<Style id="sh_spider"><IconStyle><scale>1.2</scale><Icon><href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_circle_highlight.png</href></Icon></IconStyle><LabelStyle><color>ff001111</color><scale>1.4</scale></LabelStyle><LineStyle><width>0.5</width><color>ffff111f</color></LineStyle></Style>
<Style id="sn_spider"><IconStyle><scale>0.7</scale><Icon><href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_circle_highlight.png</href></Icon></IconStyle><LabelStyle><color>ffb5b5b5</color><scale>0.9</scale></LabelStyle><LineStyle><color>00ff11ff</color></LineStyle></Style>
<StyleMap id="spider"><Pair><key>normal</key><styleUrl>#sn_spider</styleUrl></Pair><Pair><key>highlight</key><styleUrl>#sh_spider</styleUrl></Pair></StyleMap>


<Style id="2_sh_spider"><IconStyle><scale>1.2</scale><Icon><href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_circle_highlight.png</href></Icon></IconStyle><LabelStyle><color>ff110011</color><scale>1.4</scale></LabelStyle><LineStyle><width>0.5</width><color>ff11111f</color></LineStyle></Style>
<Style id="2_sn_spider"><IconStyle><scale>0.7</scale><Icon><href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_circle_highlight.png</href></Icon></IconStyle><LabelStyle><color>ff11ffb5</color><scale>0.9</scale></LabelStyle><LineStyle><color>001111ff</color></LineStyle></Style>
<StyleMap id="2_spider"><Pair><key>normal</key><styleUrl>#2_sn_spider</styleUrl></Pair><Pair><key>highlight</key><styleUrl>#2_sh_spider</styleUrl></Pair></StyleMap>


<styleUrl>#doc</styleUrl>
<Folder><name>Airports</name>
<styleUrl>#airportfolder</styleUrl>


<Placemark><name>Durham Tees Valley</name><description></description>
<Snippet maxLines="0"></Snippet><styleUrl>#2_spider</styleUrl><MultiGeometry><LineString><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>-1.426979,54.5105876,0 -1.37505058232182,54.3588196840161,8130.76624025246 -1.32350445540046,54.2070296447423,15640.4403479026 -1.27233575193875,54.0552177670135,22453.9881416349 -1.22153968418068,53.90338433094,28503.3309041539 -1.17111154230159,53.7515296120054,33728.0256022233 -1.12104669283672,53.5996538811612,38075.8688134745 -1.07134057714712,53.4477574049198,41503.4183257466 -1.02198870992187,53.2958404454444,43976.4271973102 -0.972986677715595,53.1439032606379,45470.1859409886 -0.924330137520422,52.9919461042286,45969.769413186 -0.876014815371306,52.8399692258547,45470.1859409886 -0.828036504983954,52.6879728711457,43976.4271973102 -0.780391066424406,52.5359572818033,41503.4183257466 -0.733074424809449,52.3839226956791,38075.8688134745 -0.686082569037039,52.2318693468513,33728.0256022233 -0.639411550545936,52.0797974656991,28503.3309041538 -0.593057482103787,51.9277072789755,22453.9881416349 -0.547016536622892,51.7755990098789,15640.4403479026 -0.501284946002942,51.623472878122,8130.76624025247 -0.455859000000019,51.4713291000001,0 </coordinates></LineString>
<LineString><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>-1.426979,54.5105876,0 -1.37505058232182,54.3588196840161,8130.76624025246 -1.32350445540046,54.2070296447423,15640.4403479026 -1.27233575193875,54.0552177670135,22453.9881416349 -1.22153968418068,53.90338433094,28503.3309041539 -1.17111154230159,53.7515296120054,33728.0256022233 -1.12104669283672,53.5996538811612,38075.8688134745 -1.07134057714712,53.4477574049198,41503.4183257466 -1.02198870992187,53.2958404454444,43976.4271973102 -0.972986677715595,53.1439032606379,45470.1859409886 -0.924330137520422,52.9919461042286,45969.769413186 -0.876014815371306,52.8399692258547,45470.1859409886 -0.828036504983954,52.6879728711457,43976.4271973102 -0.780391066424406,52.5359572818033,41503.4183257466 -0.733074424809449,52.3839226956791,38075.8688134745 -0.686082569037039,52.2318693468513,33728.0256022233 -0.639411550545936,52.0797974656991,28503.3309041538 -0.593057482103787,51.9277072789755,22453.9881416349 -0.547016536622892,51.7755990098789,15640.4403479026 -0.501284946002942,51.623472878122,8130.76624025247 -0.455859000000019,51.4713291000001,0 </coordinates></LineString>
<LineString><altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode><coordinates>-1.426979,54.5105876,0 -1.46306991162193,54.6452657167915,8130.76624025246 -1.4994007562172,54.7799330335197,15640.4403479026 -1.5359743201564,54.9145894238809,22453.9881416349 -1.57279343190481,55.0492347596452,28503.3309041539 -1.6098609628193,55.1838689106202,33728.0256022233 -1.64717982796325,55.3184917446126,38075.8688134745 -1.6847529869399,55.4531031273904,41503.4183257466 -1.72258344474472,55.5877029226427,43976.4271973102 -1.76067425263717,55.7222909919396,45470.1859409886 -1.79902850903249,55.8568671946911,45969.769413186 -1.83764936041401,55.9914313881044,45470.1859409886 -1.87654000226647,56.1259834271408,43976.4271973102 -1.91570368003095,56.2605231644716,41503.4183257466 -1.95514369008209,56.3950504504321,38075.8688134745 -1.99486338072804,56.5295651329761,33728.0256022233 -2.03486615323379,56.6640670576277,28503.3309041538 -2.0751554628687,56.7985560674327,22453.9881416349 -2.11573481997855,56.933032002909,15640.4403479026 -2.15660779108317,57.0674947019956,8130.76624025247 -2.19777799999999,57.201944,0 </coordinates></LineString>

<Point><coordinates>-1.426979,54.5105876,0</coordinates></Point></MultiGeometry></Placemark>

</Folder>

</Document>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Multigeometry is a child of Placemark, which has the styleUrl element. You'd do better to break them up into different Placemark elements and group them on a Folder level.

Comment: Folder is a reasonable workaround, until you want to use a StyleMap and get different styling on mouse highlight. If you style the folder, then all the children get the same style, but if you style the children, then only one at a time can get the highlight. Unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 6):

No, see the KML FAQ, they address your [question](https://developers.google.com/kml/faq#multi):

> **Can I assign different colors/styles to different geometries in a
>   MultiGeometry element**?
>
> The MultiGeometry element groups geometries
>   together in the same Placemark element. This allows the geometries to
>   share the same styling and to appear as one item in a list such as the
>   My Places pane in Google Earth.
>
> Styles are set at the Placemark level, either using a ***styleUrl*** element
>   or a Style element. Therefore, individual geometries in that Placemark
>   cannot have different styles.

Also see the workaround which I found useful:

> A frequently used workaround is to create a separate Placemark for
>   each geometry, allowing each one to have a different style. To prevent
>   a proliferation of items in a list, place them in a ***Folder*** that has a
>   ***ListStyle*** with a ***listItemType*** with ***checkHideChildren***. In Google Earth,
>   for instance, this places all the Placemarks in the same folder
>   element in My Places, and prevents the user from opening it up to
>   display a large number of elements.